# Uploading with curl with Apache proxy pass

Tags: apache, curl, mod-proxy

I have a scenario when an external client uploads a zip file to my application via curl. The application is on jboss server behind Apache with proxy pass.

So the request goes like this :

curl POST -> Apache (Proxy pass) -> Jboss (some servlet listneing)

the upload does not happen it looks it stops in Apache I get the error in apache error log.

```
(70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: error reading status line from remote server 10.31.1.52
proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /Import.do
```

the curl upload looks like this :

```
curl.exe --insecure -o IMPORT_RESP.XML -F file=@d:\temp\file_to_upload\1392209753981_pb4Mp.zip -F un=username  -F pw=password https://my.url.com/Import.do
```

the vhost config is:

```
<VirtualHost 10.31.127.254:443>

SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/4pm.si_wildcard.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/4pm.si_wildcard.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca_cert_bundle.crt

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

#ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://10.31.1.52:8080/ retry=0
ProxyPassReverse / http://10.31.1.52:8080/

ServerName my.url.com

LogLevel debug  
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/4pm/my.url.com-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/4pm/my.url.com-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase your curl's execution time by using this parameter `--max-time` as(probably) you are uploading a large file. For example 600 seconds:

```
--max-time 600
```

If the problem doesn't solve, then also try to increase the execution time for you `Import.do`(probably at apache/http)